# loading static files from other domain in sails js

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

i am using SailsJS on server side and AngularJs for client side.Both client and server are on different domains.i enabled *CORS* in sailsJS.And also in Restangular like this

```
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('URL here');
    RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  selfLink: "_links.self.href"
}); 
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
```

I Want to know if i have to load static file from SailsJS like

```
 res.sendfile("Path here/index.html");
```

it is not working here if i give "URL' in the place of "Path here"......In Short i want to load a static file of another domain from sailsJS....Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your default header when you send reseponse in your code. I see you send application/json in this code `RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});` but you want to send html file static. You can use text/html as Default Header.

Hopefully can help :D

Comment: m not talking about sending file,its done successfully when i tried connecting from client(angular) to server.Problem is when calling angular from server.

Comment: sorry , but what mean calling angular from server ?

Comment: means loading angular's static view or in broad sense main content of web app or starting point of web app from server as i described above res.sendfile("...index.html");